# A specific background image won't show up under an account on my mac

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, browser

This is the strangest issue I have ever encountered. I have a Mac running 10.6, and on every browser one specific background image does not show up. Furthermore it doesn't work in VMWare Fusion either. I decided to create a test profile to see what would happen, I open up the web page and voila, the image appears. Now if I were having the issue on one browser I would just dump the cache (have already done this on every browser) and try again. Obviously that is not the case here. This has got to be a serious one off, but hopefully someone has seen it before.

Comment: Could we possibly see the page in question?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't show it because it's a big brand and the site hasn't been launched yet. What I just noticed is that the image opens fine (when saved to disk) in Preview but not in the browser.

Comment: Would it be possible for us to see the image file? If the file is a JPEG, did you mistakenly save it as a CMYK as opposed to an RGB JPEG?

Comment: The image can be found here: [link](http://dev.parablesoft.com/bg_gift_card_middle.png). Keep in mind that this image shows up on every other computer I have looked at the page on. It consistently does not work on any browser or platform on only one computer under my usual profile. I created another profile on the same computer and it works without a problem. It leads me to believe that something is corrupted in the profile, I just have no idea what. Additionally the link I supplied above it a completely new location for the image.The image is very light so you have to look very closely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the image is very light (subtle color), I would check to see what the color depth on the computer in question is set to. Something like that might be invisible in 8-bit or 16-bit color (called "thousands" on Macs), but appear in 24-bit color (called "Millions" on Macs).

Comment: Real stupid question. Where do you change that. Don't really see anything under System Prefs > Displays > Colors. Sorry newbie on Macs.

Comment: OK figured it out. I must have screwed with the accessibility settings at some point. The contrast was up a bit over Normal. Put it back down to normal, and problem solved. Thank you for your help!